# How to copy (or reflect instantly) CSS edited on Inspected elements on the browser to the actual css file?

Tags: html, css

For example I want to change the appearance of a certain section on a web page that I'm developing, I often do this:

Inspect elements using firebug, edit the css, remember it and change it right back to my text editor which is sublime text 2. But sometimes, I change a lot and tend to forget about those changes. I tried to copy and paste the css from the browser itself after I change it, but it often copy a different version of the css.

So my question is, is there any other way that can possibly reflect the changes back to my editor as I change them on firebug? Are there any firebug addons or maybe sublime text addon which I can use to do this?

What is the most productive ways in doing this?

Comment: I dont try to remember the styles when I use Firebug+Code editor, instead I copy-paste the changes. Editors like Atom (i guess it is also the case with Sublime) correct the indentation on pasting.

Comment: Hi versvs, is it safe to do this? Can firebug produce every single line of code that I did? I tried it and some comments are removed.

Comment: If you are coding a lot, you'd better be using and editor that let's you see the changes in real time (see @Justinas reply), for me it is safe to do the firebug copypasting cause when I'm on that case i am always doing minor tweaks that can be easily transported. If you're coding a lot of stuff in firebug, i cannot say if my method is OK :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved:** Use firebug addon cssupdater to save css edits in firebug.

There is a firefox addon for saving css changes in firebug **(cssupdater)**. 
You edit your css in firebug then click Sync Now button to sync the changes to your local css file.

You will need to install addon and a desktop app, read details on their page.

### Links:

http://www.cssupdater.com/

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cssupdater/

Answer (score 0):

Use some IDE instead of text editor, that will allow you to see webpage directly in IDE (e.g. DreamViewer).

Comment: Thanks Justin. You mean Dreamweaver right? Anyway, my problem with using that is a lot of times it doesn't exactly how it suppose to look like than in the browser version. For example, the foundation framework has its column not aligned or something like that. That's why I stopped using it. I hope there's an alternate for Dreamweaver though.